# Nginx too many redirects error when using upstreams

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have the following nginx config

```
upstream test1 {
     server 10.0.1.8:33284;
     server 10.0.3.9:32783;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test1.example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://test.example.com redirect;
}

server {
      listen 443;
      server_name test.example.com;
      location / {
          proxy_pass http://test1;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the following

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
```